# Wait for specific keypress in a function (press enter to continue)

Tags: org-mode, wrapping

I have a function to underline Chinese characters with zero width spaces in org-mode.

```lisp
(defun ctext-uline-begin ()
  "Underscore with invisible space before for underlining Chinese texts."
  (insert "​_"))

(defun ctext-uline-end ()
    "Underscore with invisible space after for underlining Chinese texts."
  (insert "_​"))

(defun ctext-underline()
  (interactive)
  (if (region-active-p)
      (progn
          (goto-char (region-end))
          (ctext-uline-end)
          (goto-char (region-beginning))
          (ctext-uline-begin)))
  (progn
    (ctext-uline-begin)
    (read-event "Press Enter to Complete.")
    (ctext-uline-end)))
```

The function wraps "_" with zero width spaces around the Chinese characters when region is active.

When no region is selected, I'd like it to insert `uline-begin`, wait for user to hit <kbd>RET</kbd>, then insert `uline-end`.

The above function almost did it.

How do we get the user to 'Press Enter to Continue' in Elisp?

Comment: `read-from-minibuffer` or `read-char` will help with that.

Comment: Please remove tag `elisp` from the question. See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info. Thx.